# powershell script to change column position in text file

Tags: powershell

Do you know how to use powershell to move column DocumentNo to last column ?

```
| D|Ref.Doc.  |Row|DocumentNo     |CoCd|Pstng Date
| W|5007534739|  1|65713191       |STCD|01/17/2016
| W|5007534739|  1|65713191       |STCD|01/17/2016
| W|5007534739|  1|65713191       |STCD|01/17/2016
```

Expected output

```
| D|Ref.Doc.  |Row|CoCd|Pstng Date|DocumentNo       
| W|5007534739|  1|STCD|01/17/2016|65713191       
| W|5007534739|  1|STCD|01/17/2016|65713191       
| W|5007534739|  1|STCD|01/17/2016|65713191
```

Here the command that I've tried

```
(get-content $file -ReadCount 0) |
foreach  {
'{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}|{5}|{6}|{4}' -f $_.split('|')
} | Set-Content $file2
```

The code works properly, but in case DocumentNo containt a pipe as data, how to handle it ?

Comment: How to implement the command in power script ? How actually it works ? thanks

Comment: I've tried something, but in case pipe is a data instead of delimiter, how can we handle this ?

Comment: If there is a leading pipe why not just hardcode it in? A "proper" CSV like file would not use the delimeter as data.

Comment: `% {$Match=[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]::Empty} {if(-not $Match.Success) {$Match=[Regex]::Match($_,'\|DocumentNo\s*(?=\|)')} $_.Remove($Match.Index,$Match.Length) + $_.Substring($Match.Index,$Match.Length)}`

Comment: I tired to understand the code but failed, would you please share what it did ?

Comment: Don't worry. @PetSerAl doesn't believe in proper answers. He's doing pretty much the same as my solution below except I use regex to modify all lines while he uses methods of the `String`-class. To explain his code: He runs a regex-match to find your column's `index` (start position) and `length` (until next column). The match is only executed once (header only), then for all lines he removes the text from the start position `index` and the following `length` number of characters and adds the same text to the end of the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A delimeter is no good if it's used inside the data itself as it breaks the csv. I see that the data is fixed width (though the length and index may change from file to file), so I would take a different apporach.

1. Find the location for the DocumentNo-column. You can use regex for this (https://regex101.com/r/pH2oL9/1). I use `[Regex]::Match()` because it returns `index` (start position) and `length` (number of characters) of a match (the column).
2. Create a regex that finds the content at the same position and length on every line. It makes groups for "before", "content", "after"  by counting "any character" until the start position I've decided, then the length of the column, then "until end of line". I use subexpressions `$()` in the regex to insert the `index` and `length` from step 2 since they might not be the same for every file.
3. Use `-replace` with the generated regex to modify the text on each line (since `$text` is an array). `-replace` finds the groups, and by using `$1$3$2` I can say which order I want the groups inserted in the result. (https://regex101.com/r/vE6vO9/1)

Solution:

```
#Sample text
$text = Get-Content .\Test.txt

#Analyze header (find DocumentNo placement in fixed-width file) and create regex
$regex = [regex]::Match($text[0], '\|DocumentNo\s+') | ForEach-Object { "^(.{$($_.Index)})(.{$($_.Length)})(.*)$" }

#Modify text
$text -replace $regex, '$1$3$2' | Set-Content .\TestOut.txt
```

TestOut.txt

```
| D|Ref.Doc.  |Row|CoCd|Pstng Date|DocumentNo     
| W|5007534739|  1|STCD|01/17/2016|65713191       
| W|5007534739|  1|STCD|01/17/2016|65713191       
| W|5007534739|  1|STCD|01/17/2016|65713191
```

You might want to trim the trailing whitespaces. Use `Trim()` for this:

```
$text -replace $regex, '$1$3$2' | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() } | Set-Content .\TestOut.txt
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot. Appreciate if you could explain how the analyze header works and how it use in modify test.

Comment: I've added a description and regex101 links which will explain the regexes.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
$delimiter = "|"
$data = Get-Content "c:\tmp\test.csv";
$newCsv= ($data|Foreach-object { ($_ -split $delimiter)[@(0..3;5;6;4)] -join  $delimiter})

# Set the new-ordered column content to the new-file

$newCsv|Set-Content C:\tmp\test2.csv
```

If you want all of this into one line you can do the following:

```
Get-Content "c:\tmp\test.csv"|Foreach-object { ($_ -split '|')[@(0..3;5;6;4)] -join '|'}|Set-Content C:\tmp\test2.csv
```

Note that you cannot use set-content if you have get-content as a part of the pipeline, because the file will be open and cannot replace it's content as a part of the stream.

You'd have to use either the first approach (read the content first, then pass it to the stream) or set the content into a different file.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried and it works but I've case where pipe delimiter can be a data instead of delimiter.